# Run migrations from specific project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have 3 projects in solution.

Here is how it's look like

[image]

My Migrations is under `TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure`

In `Startup.cs` under TooSeeWeb I have this code

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure")));
```

Here is ApplicationDbContext code

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Proposals> Proposals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppUser> IdentityUsers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TermsOfUse> TermsOfUse { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Privacy> Privacy { get; set; }


    public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>> IdentityUserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookmarkFolder> BookmarkFolders { get; set; }
}
```

But when in `TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure` I run `dotnet ef database update` I have this error

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

But when I run `dotnet ef database update -s ../TooSeeWeb` all okay.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Where is your context in ? Not in the same as the migration ?
Note: You ended your question with "it's all OK - how can I fix this".

Comment: Context as migrations in TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure @Holger

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use IdentityDbContext? If not, use DbContext and override the OnConfiguring method so that you can state your connection string as follows:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connectionString");
        }
    }
}
```